# TCP STUN Client - To check NAT Type behaviour

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, nat, stun

I want to check NAT type and its behaviour with STUN server available (Public Stun Servers) ([STUNTMAN](https://stun.stunprotocol.org:3478)). I have tried and found client codes ([STUN CLIENT](https://github.com/moien007/STUN)) which can communicate with STUN server to identify NAT behaviour, but all are in UDP. As per [RFC-5780](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5780) we can check Mapping behaviour for UDP and TCP, Hence I want to check the same using TCP and i have implemented the same way as UDP does but both results differs. So, will behaviour/Steps to find NAT behaviour be the same as UDP or need to implement other way.
Any Sample client code will also be helpful.

Comment: The [Stuntman](http://www.stunprotocol.org/) client has a TCP mode.  `stunclient stun.stunprotocol.org --protocol tcp`

Comment: I have installed stuntman:
[code block]brew install stuntman
Then run with:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/stuntman/1.2.16/bin/stunclient stunserver.stunprotocol.org --protocol udp

/opt/homebrew/Cellar/stuntman/1.2.16/bin/stunclient stunserver.stunprotocol.org --protocol tcp

commands result with different ports like
Binding test: success
Local address: 192.168.1.115:52351
Mapped address: xx.xx.xx.xx:18840

Answer (score 0):

STUN/TURN check the NAT type by simulating the connection of several differnt types, and step by step it can split Full Cone, Restricted NAT, Port Restricted NAT and Symmetric NAT.

We usually use UDP cause we don't need three way heandshake to establishe a connection, which may confuse the judgement of NAT types. So if you want to use TCP, you need first know how STUN check NAT types step by step for UDP, and think about what will happen for TCP three-way handshake. It can not just copy the code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have gone through the RFC definition and the steps for determining NAT type. I have followed the same steps define in RFC standard for TCP (Followed TCP protocol definition) not just copied the code, but result differs. So asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS:
Install stuntman:

```
homebrew install stuntman
```

Then run:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/stuntman/1.2.16/bin/stunclient stunserver.stunprotocol.org --mode behavior 



Binding test: success
        Local address: 192.168.1.115:56027
        Mapped address: xx.xx.xx.xx:19319
        Behavior test: success
    Nat behavior: Endpoint Independent Mapping
```